# cp/rsync both grind to a halt when copying to USB/Micro SD

Tags: arch-linux, rsync, cp, file-copy, sd-card

I'm trying to transfer about 20GB of music from my Arch Linux laptop to a Micro SD card, via a USB reader. The process starts off fine; the first ~50 songs take a combined one second, although from what I've read that's just to do with caching (or something...) and doesn't represent the actual speed. Then it goes to what I'd consider a reasonable speed, where each song takes anywhere between one and five seconds (the files are lossless, so maybe ~15mb on average).

However, after a few hundred songs, things just slow down completely. A single file will take about five minutes to transfer, and that's a conservative estimate. I left it running overnight and barely any progress had been made!

The card is a recently purchased class 10 Sandisk, and I've tried using it in both a USB and a regular SD card adapter, so I'd like to try some OS-level solutions before I investigate further into the physical side of things. I've also tried all three USB ports on my laptop and they all face the same issue. I've tried using the regular `cp -rv ~/music /mnt/sd` command, as well as `rsync -rvh ~/music /mnt/sd`, and the same thing happens with both. If, for testing purposes, I copy to a destination on the same partition then everything's fine, so it's definitely to do with it being on a different partition. I've also tried the suggestion posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/131285) which didn't help.

My kernel version is 4.10.9.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly the issue must be because of your ram capacity or IO read/write
When you copy files the data is stored into your ram then copied to the destination, since you are copying large files of upto 20gb, the issue could be because of the limited ram, if ram is not the case then there could be a bottle neck because of the IO read/write capacity ( though this should not result in a halt ). Check stats if there is a CPU overload. would prefer using "sar -P ALL" command to check CPU load stats. Also try checking stats for ram usage.